# Card report in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, layout, oracle-apex

I have created a classical report with Cards template. But I noticed that the output is unexpected. The SQL query as below

```
SELECT 'col m6' column_css_classes
        ,'<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentmorneau/material-apex/master/docs/img/sample-1.jpg">' img
        ,'Card Title' title
        ,'I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.' content
        ,'#' btn_link_1
        ,'This is a link' btn_label_1
        ,'#' btn_link_2
        ,null btn_label_2
FROM     dual
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Card Report] [image: Expected output]

Comment: What is your question? Why the result is unexpected? What would you expect?

Comment: @Typo the left image attached is the actual result and the right image is the expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your image (the expected result) is from this [website](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=12192:22:::NO:::).

If i'm correct then you should go to the [github](https://github.com/vincentmorneau/material-apex) of this project and fallow the instructions there on how to install that template into your apex application. After you install the template just then you can use that sql query and get the same output as in your picture.